# react : How to disappear the error field?

Tags: reactjs

When the user selects the date, the error should disappear but here even after selecting the date it is showing me the error field. Where am I going wrong ?

[image]

### Here's the code :

```
    handleChangeDate = (date,type) =>{
            let error=true
            console.log('date',date)
            if(type==='due_date'){
                error=false
                this.setState({ due_date : date})       
            }
            if(error){
                this.setState({
                    [type]:date,
                    [type+"_error"]:""
                })
            } 
        }
   

     render(){
    return(
        <div style={{width:"100%"}}>
                      <DatePicker
                       dateFormat="MM/dd/yyyy"
                       margin="normal"
                       selected={due_date}
                       placeholderText={"Due Date"}
                       onChange={date=>this.handleChangeDate(date,'due_date')}
                       maxDate={new Date()}
                       className={`milestone-input-due-date`}
                      />
                      <img src={DROP_D} alt="drop down" style={{cursor:'pointer'}} className='dropdown-milestone'/>                                                        
          </div>
                                                
                      {due_date_error && (
                            <div className="input-error-style">{due_date_error}</div>
                       )}
    )
  }
```

Comment: Set `due_date_error` to `null`.

Comment: As @BenM suggested setting `due_date_error` to `null` or `""` will work.